# jdbc to oracle 11g xe. class not found error

Tags: java, jdbc

I've installed oracle 10g express edition. I need to connect it to java program, used jdbc. I have ojdbc6_g.jar and set its class path. I am getting class not found error.Code is given below. Please help

```java
import java.sql.*;

public class OraThin {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@//Terminator:1521/CLRExtProc", "scott", "tiger"); //hostname=Terminator, sid=CLRxtProc
            Statement s = con.createStatement();
            s.execute("insert into student values('PQR',10)");
            s.close();
            con.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The stack trace:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver at 
java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366) at 
java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355) at 
java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) at 
java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354) at 
java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423) at 
sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308) at 
java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356) at 
java.lang.ClassLoader.forName0(Native Method) at OraThin.main(OraThin.java:6)
```

Comment: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366) at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355) at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354) at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423) at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308) at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)   at java.lang.ClassLoader.forName0(Native Method) at OraThin.main(OraThin.java:6)

Comment: i guess the jar with that class is not on the classpath.

Comment: how are you running it? through an IDE or on the command line?

Comment: @aldrin: through command prompt

Comment: have you tried running it as suggested by Jayan in the answers below?

Comment: @aldrin: yes it gives error:could not find or load main class oracle\ojdbc6_g.jar

Comment: @evryone: I am using jdk 1.7 on windows 7

Comment: @everyone: Friends please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Please 'copy paste' the exact command line..

Comment: Both OraThin.class and ojdbc6_g.jar are in the same directory. Commanline is java -classpath 'ojdbc6_g.jar;.' Orathin

Comment: @Rak.  That should have worked.  try java -verbose  option.   Is the jar file downloaded correctly?  Open it using some zip tools and see if it has classes.

Comment: @Jayan: Thanks for your help. It didn't work out.

Comment: @Rak.. Could you try passing -verbose and see the loading of classes

Comment: @Jayan: I was so frustated that I uninstalled 10g xe. now I am trying to connect with 11g R2. but similar connectivity  problems.

Comment: @Rak : Oh, after seeing the answer to Adrins comment, the class not found is solved. You should accept the answer (and upvote answers some answers if you like)..  And post another question for 'data read' exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jar is not in the class path. You could try

`java -classpath 'path to ojdbc6_g.jar;.' OraThin`

ojdbc6_g.jar is debug version, hence its name is bit different. May be your scripts are looking for ojdbc6.jar or ojdbc6.jar
(If you are using an IDE, you will able to create a library and add to the project module).

Comment: it gives error:could not find or load main class oracle\ojdbc6_g.jar

Answer (score 1):

Try these steps to debug your problem:

- Make sure the ojdbc6_g.jar file is not corrupted. Open it in an archive app like Winzip or 7-Zip and check that it opens without errors
- Copy the ojdbc6_g.jar into the same folder as OraThin.class file and execute the following exactly as below:

  java -cp ojdbc6_g.jar; OraThin

Hopefully you will resolve your problem soon

Comment: now it shows the following message java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: No more data to read from socket at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngine.unmarshallUB1(T4CMAREngine.java:1157) at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8TIpro.receive(T4C8TIpro.java:129) at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.connect(T4CConnection.java1124) at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4Connection.java:320) at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:546) at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:236) at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:32)

Comment: hmm it seems that you are trying to access a 10g version with a 11g driver. I would suggest you download the driver that matches your db version from this page http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/jdbc/index-091264.html and use that instead

Comment: +1.   This answer is complete. The new exception could go into a new question.

Answer (score 0):

This will definitely work, your code is absolutely correct. Please set the classpath correctly or alternatively you may also use ojdbc6.jar file to solve your problem.C:

Try this :
    1: open command prompt
    2: go to the path where your java files present
    3: type
          set classpath=.;C:\oraclexe.....\ojdbc14.jar;%classpath%
    4: compile your code with javac -d . filename.java

Tell me what it shows.

Comment: I tried,   java -classpath 'C:\Users\Rakesh\Downloads\jdbc oracle\ojdbc6.jar;.' OraThin

Comment: it gives error:could not find or load main class oracle\ojdbc6.jar

Comment: Why don't you try ojdbc14.jar

Comment: same error : could not find or load main class oracle\ojdbc14.jar

Answer (score 0):

You can find the jar at the following location
[oracle install folder]\app\oracle\product\10.2.0\server\jdbc\lib

look for ojdbc14.jar and use it in the classpath as suggested above.

Example: D:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\10.2.0\server\jdbc\lib\ojdbc14.jar

Answer (score 0):

after searching for about 10 days finally got answer to my own question. No error or exception. connection successfully established. just needed to do following things
1. set path c:\jdk1.7.0\bin;c:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\10.2.0\server\BIN
2. set classpath=.;c:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\10.2.0\server\jdbc\lib\ojdbc14.jar

Answer (score 0):

Go your project, properties > library > add jar > add ojdb7.jar