# JDBC Driver class not found: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver in oracle 11g

Tags: java

i wrote a program to connect to the database in java 1.7 and my database is oracle 11g express edition iam getting class not found error for the class OracleDriver?

Comment: have you included the driver jar in the classpath?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jdbc to oracle 11g xe. class not found error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9272124/jdbc-to-oracle-11g-xe-class-not-found-error)

Comment: i have set my classpath to C:\app\raju\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\jdbc\lib\ojdbc6_g.jar            this path but still iam getting the error

Answer (score 1):

This error message is clearly says that there is not a `JDBC` driver in your class path.

```
JDBC Driver class not found: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver in oracle 11g
```

You need to add oracle `JDBC` driver in your class path.

So first [download](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/jdbc-112010-090769.html) it, then add it your class path.

Comment: what do you mean by posting that path ?

Comment: i have set my classpath to C:\app\raju\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\jdbc\lib\ojdbc6_g.jar            this path but still iam getting the error

Comment: No way, the error message is clear enough to tell yea that there is no JDBC driver in your class path, just check it out.